# load balancing percona with haproxy

Tags: mysql, haproxy, percona

I am trying to configure ha-proxy for percona DB with 3 different nodes. My configuration goes as follows-

```
backend mysql_backend
mode tcp
option tcplog
balance leastconn
option httpchk default-server port 9200 inter 5s downinter 10s  rise 3 fall 2 maxconn 256
server  percona1  percona-1:3306 check port <port_num> inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3 maxconn 450
server  percona2 percona-2:3306 check port <port_num> inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3 maxconn 450 backup
server  percona3 percona-3:3306 check port <port_num> inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3 maxconn 450 backup
```

In the above configuration,`*maxconn 450*` specifies the maximal number of concurrent connections that will be sent to this server1 i.e. percona1. Now interesting thing that pop up in my mind, what if

1. number of connection reach to 450 and another request comes?? Will the 451st request will be queued or it will be forwarded to percona2/percona3(which is a back up server in case percona1 fail but here percona1 did not fail but reach to limit)
2. Percona1(my.conf) configured such as it can handle as many as 250  connection at a time but from proxy server, it gets more than 250 like 450 as it is configured in proxy server.

My question is what will happen in the above scenarios??

I have read documentation however i dint get any clear information. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're talking about Percona XtraDb Cluster because using HAproxy in this fashion with 3 separate MySQL instances is going to lead to disaster (if they are separate instances, re-architect now!!). Here are the answers to your questions:

1. If config'ed for maxconn of 450, the 451st connection will be queued and wait for an open connection to the server. (the [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.2) is pretty clear) *One point to note is that you should check the the `ulimit -n` of the HAproxy process to make sure that it has a connection limit of more than 1350 (450 * 3 nodes)*
2. I'm not completely sure I understand the question, but if you're referring to the `max_connections`parameter for `mysqld`then you should set that parameter slightly higher than the HAproxy `maxconn`value for that particular server to avoid timeouts

Comment: thanks a lot @jtobs for your attention. Yes you are right, I am talking about  Percona XtraDB Cluster (Server version: 5.6.29). 1. Haproxy has max connection as 4000 defined in global section,so that's not an issue. My question is what will happen for the 451st connection request on node1 as node2 and node3 are set as **backup** server and node1 is already reached to its limit and can not take any more request.Will the 451st connection is queued or it will be forwarded to node2??For question 2-I am referring to the _max_connections_ parameter for mysqld.

Comment: and @jtobs I would certainly like to know the consequences. What could go wrong if I do the configuration like above (all of them are separate instances).Please educate me on this issue.

Comment: @ripan I can't think of many reasons why you would set them as `backup`. If you're work is mostly reads, then use all of the resources available to you. You've also specified a `balancing` rule, but if only one node is set w/o `backup`, load balancing is pointless. Regarding the 451st connection, it will be queued for the server1 and not forwarded to the others. Also, unless you specify `allbackup` only 1 backup server will be used. Regarding a larger conversation on consequences, this forum is not designed for that purpose; I would recommend testing or engaging an expert. good luck!!

Comment: Best forum will be below links related to Mysql percona cluster + Haproxy
http://severalnines.com/blog
https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster

Comment: Use the FORCE LUKE, build the percona nodes into a CLUSTER, like they were intended, and i believe this answer is referring to that as a point. (disasters and all)